# Using delimiter on a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My Question is how i can use the delimiter without jumping to the next line

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadTextFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));
        read.useDelimiter(";");

        while (read.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(read.next());
        }
    }
}
```

My text file:

```
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;hallo;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;wie;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;gehts;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
```

My output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I want my output like a table with more columns like in the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Delimiter to `\n`. Using `;` means that every entry is a number between those `;`.

try this

```
public class Readtextfile {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));
            read.useDelimiter("\n"); // It is the default delimiter, you can skip this line.

            while(read.hasNext()){
                 String str= read.next().replaceAll(";","");
                 System.out.println(str));

            }

        }

    }
```

Otherwise try to read by line and then use `split(";")` to construct your output.

Comment: When i use your first solution how can i get rid of the ";" ?

Comment: I edited my answer:  `String str= read.next().replace(";","");` basically replace `";"` with `""`. You can also `replaceAll` if you got more that one `;`. It works similarly.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `read.useDelimiter(";");` and use `read.next().split(";");` instead.

My solution could be more simple with `replace`but you asked for the output to be in columns, so I thought this was what you meant with it.

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));

  while(read.hasNext()){

    String[] line = read.next().split(";");
    for(String s : line){
        System.out.print(s + "\t");
    }
        System.out.println();
  }
```

Output:

```
1   1   1   1   
1   EDC 1   1   
1   1   1   1   
1   AVC 1   1   
1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1
```

If you do note care about formatting the output, then you might want to use:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));
while(read.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(read.next().replace(";", ""));
}
```

Output:

```
1111
1EDC11
1111
1AVC11
1111
1111
```